# Read operation exception MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I have both MongoDb and the Spring MVC app running on the same machine. For some reason I get the read operation error when trying to access the data through my Spring MVC app.

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /192.168.1.79:28017 failed on database utilDb
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:253)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
        at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
        at com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:399)
        at com.mongodb.DB.collectionExists(DB.java:441)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$5.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:438)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$5.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:436)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:372)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:48)
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)
        at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
        at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:142)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
        ... 45 more
```

Here is the config I have on the app.xml in Spring :

```
    <!-- Mongo DB Conf -->
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="192.168.1.79"></property>
    <property name="port" value="28017"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="utilDb"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance for any inputs.

Comment: Can you confirm that MongoDB is running and that it's available on that port (and that your firewall isn't blocking it? You're not using the loopback 127.0.0.1). Try just connecting to the instance with the shell via `mongo 192.168.1.179'

Comment: are you really running your mongodb on 28017, and not the default port of 27017?  by default 28017 is the http port not DB port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual port that MongoDB server starts on is 27017 where you are using 28017.  Try changing that to 27017 and see if that helps you.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Did not realize I was using the web console port. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
options.connectionsPerHost = 100;
options.maxWaitTime = 2000;
options.socketKeepAlive = true;
options.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 50;
```

if you use spring template, just config as follow:

```
<mongo:mongo host="${mongodb.server}" port="${mongodb.port}">
    <mongo:options  
      connections-per-host="${mongo.connectionsPerHost}"  
      threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-    multiplier="${mongo.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier}"  
         connect-timeout="${mongo.connectTimeout}"  
         max-wait-time="${mongo.maxWaitTime}"  
         auto-connect-retry="${mongo.autoConnectRetry}"  
         socket-keep-alive="${mongo.socketKeepAlive}"  
         socket-timeout="${mongo.socketTimeout}"     
/>
```